# MediaCapture change camera focus(WP8.1 and WinRt8.1)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I use MediaCapture like this

```
MediaCapture _capture = new MediaCapture();
await _capture.InitializeAsync();
await _capture.StartPreviewAsync();
```

and camera work. But I need to change camera focus from code. Did you know how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

MediaCapture class has a property [VideoDeviceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.capture.mediacapture.videodevicecontroller.aspx) which returns [device controller](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.devices.videodevicecontroller.aspx).

You will find there all the properties of your camera along with [focus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.devices.videodevicecontroller.focus.aspx) and [FocusControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.devices.focuscontrol.aspx). I've managed to change focus like this:

```
// first set mode to manual
await _capture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.SetPresetAsync(Windows.Media.Devices.FocusPreset.Manual);
await _capture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.SetValueAsync(100);
// but those two above are deprecated - it will work but I would advise to do it:
_capture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.Configure(new FocusSettings { Mode = FocusMode.Manual, Value = 100, DisableDriverFallback = true });
await _capture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.FocusAsync();
```

Comment: But what about VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.FocusAsync(). Why this call didn't focus camera? And How use SetDeviceProperty set focus to Auto

Comment: And I try to get VideoDeviceController.Focus.Capabilities.Supported and always return false.

Comment: I try to do something like this `VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.SetPresetAsync(FocusPreset.AutoMacro);` and look like camera focused but `_capture.FocusChanged += _capture_FocusChanged;` didn't fired

Comment: @Std_Net I'll try to play with it later. But have you tried to change [focusmode to manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.media.devices.focusmode.aspx)?

Comment: camera focused, but event _capture_FocusChanged on phone didn't fired :( as I understand now to get live data from camera(for example get frames for barcode decode) I can get only use CapturePhotoToStreamAsync but in this case phone always play camera system sound. and I didn't find way to turn off this sound from my code

Comment: @Std_Net Yes, I saw your other question. As for focus changed - I'm not sure but it may be connected with Mode.Auto. With manual it may be easier as you change the focus, and just after `await FocusAsync();` you should perform method OnFocusChanged or othen event you implemented.

Comment: Have you checked the VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.FocusChangedSupported property?

Comment: @Jensen If I would write the app that would control the focus, then yes - I would have checked for the focus support. Though I;m not sure if there is a camera without this feature.

Answer (score 3):

You can focus using this line

```
_mediaCapture.VideoDeviceController.FocusControl.FocusAsync();
```

call this on a event, like on `CaptureElement` tapped event or set a focus button and call this when focus button is clicked or call it just before capturing the photo so the photo is captured after focusing.